# Is it possible to hide #Value in a long formula? I tried IFERROR but excel said there's too many arguments

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to make a calendar that changes dynamically based on year/month entered.

Cell formula for cell F11 is:

`=IF(OR(E11="",VALUE(E11)>EOMONTH(DATEVALUE(1&B5&Year),0)-EOMONTH(DATEVALUE(1&B5&Year),-1)-1), "",E11+1)`

FYI, the link for spreadsheet:
https://1drv.ms/x/s!AqB4pWPNC0Uche8l1X-RaumvmRwBkA?e=yhlIb2

Comment: You posted your original formula, but not where you tried to put the IFERROR.

Answer (score 0):

The “You’ve entered too many arguments…” doesn't have to do with how long the formula is, it simply means you have put it in the wrong place (probably inside the IF but without nesting it.)

The simplest way to use `IFERROR` is to wrap the whole formula in it, like this:

`=IFERROR(IF(OR(E11="",VALUE(E11)>EOMONTH(DATEVALUE(1&B5&Year),0)-EOMONTH(DATEVALUE(1&B5&Year),-1)-1), "",E11+1),"")`

Answer (score -1):

If you want to hide #VALUE! in a lengthy formula, you can use the IFERROR function, but it may not work if there are too many arguments. One solution is to split the formula into smaller parts and apply IFERROR on each part. This way, if an error occurs, the formula will return an empty string. Another solution is to use ISERROR instead of IFERROR if you have an older version of Excel, as it does the same thing.

Option 1: Split the formula into smaller parts and use IFERROR on each part.

Original formula:

```
=IF(OR(E11="",VALUE(E11)>EOMONTH(DATEVALUE(1&B5&Year),0)-EOMONTH(DATEVALUE(1&B5&Year),-1)-1), "",E11+1)
```

Rewritten formula:

```
=IF(OR(E11="", IFERROR(VALUE(E11)>IFERROR(EOMONTH(DATEVALUE(1&B5&Year),0)-EOMONTH(DATEVALUE(1&B5&Year),-1)-1, ""), "")), "", E11+1)
```

Option 2: Use ISERROR instead of IFERROR.

Original formula:

```
=IF(OR(E11="",VALUE(E11)>EOMONTH(DATEVALUE(1&B5&Year),0)-EOMONTH(DATEVALUE(1&B5&Year),-1)-1), "",E11+1)
```

Rewritten formula:

```
=IF(OR(E11="", IF(ISERROR(VALUE(E11)>EOMONTH(DATEVALUE(1&B5&Year),0)-EOMONTH(DATEVALUE(1&B5&Year),-1)-1), ""), ""), E11+1)
```

Note that both rewritten formulas should have the same result as the original formula.

Comment: "***...but it may not work if there are too many arguments***" what does that mean? To many arguments where?